# how to get the value of the src in Bootsrtap carousel

Tags: jquery

I want to create a function whitout parameters to capture the value of the src and call the value in an URL in a form. I don't know how to use a return instead console.log

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#carouselExampleIndicators').carousel();
    $('#carouselExampleIndicators').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
        var src = $('.active').find('img').attr('src');
               console.log(src);
    });

});
```

Comment: Where on your `carousel`  code ?

Comment: save the src into a variable, that you initialize outside of your function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the carrousel code but i dont think it ll help you.

```
 <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <?php foreach ($lesPhotos as $k => $unePhoto) :
                    if ($k != 0):?>
                        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="<?= $k ?>"></li>
                    <?php endif;
                endforeach; ?>

            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <?php foreach ($lesPhotos as $k => $unePhoto) : ?>
                    <!--        <a href="index.php?uc=observer&photo=--><? //=$photoAmatcher ?><!--&matcher=--><? //=$lesPhotos[$k] ?><!--?action=validerMatcher">-->
                    <!--            <img src="img/accept.png" alt="Matcher">-->
                    <div class="carousel-item <?php if ($k == 0) {echo "active";} ?>">

                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="<?= $CheminDossierImages . $lesPhotos[$k] ?>"
                             alt="<?= $CheminDossierImages . $lesPhotos[$k] ?>">
                    </div>

                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code but doen't work

```
window.src=0;
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#carouselExampleIndicators').carousel();
    $('#carouselExampleIndicators').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
        src = $('.active').find('img').attr('src');
             
    });
    console.log(src);
});
```